# Loading/Routing Angular 2 (official v2.0.0)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

How the router should be configured if I have to access an angular2 app
page directly (without any `router-outlet` directives)

The tricky moment comes when the app have to be opened in iframe.

 
So **iframe.src**=`localhost/PathParam1/PathParam2/ng2/page1`

Do you have any idea what the URL_BASE_HREF is supposed to be, or what I missed.

For the previous versions of angular (all to RC6), URL_BASE_HREF was `http://localhost/PathParam1/PathParam2/ng2`

and the routing worked then.

Now when I`m using the same logic, but if I load the app at

```
localhost/PathParam1/PathParam2/ng2/page1
```

and then it`s automatically changed to

```
localhost/somePathParam/someOtherPathParam/ng2/PathParam1/PathParam2/ng2/page1
```

Do you have any idea how this could be done?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is solved already. I created a small lib which provides current the base url. For example if I have `localhost/PathParam1/PathParam2/ng2/page1` the method will return `localhost/PathParam1/PathParam2/ng2` and then I have children navigation to `page1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved already. I created a small lib which provides current the base url. For example if I have localhost/PathParam1/PathParam2/ng2/page1 the method will return localhost/PathParam1/PathParam2/ng2 and then I have children navigation to page1